# migrating sendmail mailboxes to postfix

Tags: postfix, sendmail

I'm planning to migrate our current sendmail box to a postfix server, but first of all is it possible to export all our clients mailboxes from sendmail to our virtual mysql postfix setup? if yes, how to do so?

Any comments will be appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Postfix can deliver to mbox files just fine, no work needed.  Just make sure that your `mailbox_command` or `virtual_mailbox_maps` points to the correctly.

Comment: there are some scripts which do mailbox to maildir conversion, it should be a good idea to switch to maildir now, in a single sweep

Comment: If you're using an LDA that does maildir (Dovecot, hopefully), yeah, good idea.